# Slideshow with customized links for each slide

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

I want to create a slideshow with customized links on each slide. So far, I'm able to use a jQuery to add in images which appears in a slideshow. How do I include different text or buttons for each image?

An example is seen in this website: baronfig.com

PS Any joomla extensions which have this would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Joomla site, then just use one of these sliders. They have what you are looking for

[SMART SLIDER](https://www.nextendweb.com/smart-slider/)
[REVOLUTION SLIDER](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/22599)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example for an idea. 
as you can see the pictures are in absolute position a link is over them.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #09C;
}
.contImages{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.contImages img{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.contImages a{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #C63;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next').click(function(){
        $('.contImages:first').appendTo('#container')
        })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
      <div class="contImages" style="background-color:red"><a href="#">aaaaa</a><img src="../immagini/foto/ingrandimenti/botti.jpg" width="520" height="300"></div>
      <div class="contImages" style="background-color:green"><a href="#">bbbb</a><img src="../immagini/foto/ingrandimenti/donna.jpg" width="520" height="300"></div>
      <div class="contImages" style="background-color:blue"><a href="#">cccc</a><img src="../immagini/foto/ingrandimenti/donnaaaa.jpg" width="520" height="300"></div>
      <div class="contImages" style="background-color:pink"><a href="#">dddd</a><img src="../immagini/foto/ingrandimenti/faccia.jpg" width="520" height="300"></div>
  </div>
  <input name="" type="button" id="next" value="next">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Creating a beautiful slider with Joomla banner component with FREE extension.
try this [banner slideshow module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/26081).

- Tracking clicks and hits.
- Tracking impression.
- Choose proper category.
- 10+ Slide effects
- Random mode for all effects.

Hope its helps..